# Generating a list of evenly distributed round numbers within a range from min to max

Tags: javascript, math, range, sequence

I'm trying to take a column filled with numbers and use the min and max values to generate a list of filter ranges for a user to filter the table by. Using the naive approach ends up with hard to process number ranges and I'd really rather have round numbers that could work regardless of the min/max values.

I've seen this question several places, and think the best answer I've found so far is [Stuart Ainsworth's number table answer](http://codegumbo.com/index.php/2009/01/25/building-ranges-using-a-dynamically-generated-numbers-table/), but I would like to have steps that are very round.

For instance, if I need to generate 4 ranges from 0-100000, the numbers will be:

```
0     - 25000
25000 - 50000
50000 - 75000
75000 - 100000
```

If, however, my min and max are oddball numbers, I can get awkward to consume ranges.

Example: if I need to generate 5 ranges from -1234 to 4321, the ranges are:

```
-1234 - -123
-123  -  988
988   - 2099
2099  - 3210
3210  - 4321
```

I would prefer ranges like:

```
-1234 - 0          -1234 -  0          -1234 - -100
0     - 1000        0    -  1000       -100  -  1000
1000  - 2100        1000 -  2000        1000 -  2100
2100  - 3200        2000 -  3000        2100 -  3200
3200  - 4321        3000 -  4321        3200 -  4321
```

Or something similar. The ranges need to be *close* in size to one another, but it's much more important that the numbers be easy to glance at and consume.

Comment: An "arithmetic progression" will solve this. Pointedly, a custom function that takes a value and returns the value you want. Might need two functions. One for the lower bound of the value, and one for the upper. I will post a solution shortly, if I can get it to work

Comment: @GetSet, does it, though? Wouldn't an arithmetic progression be a fixed range, whereas the OP has indicated an interest in fuzzing the numbers/range in order to produce easier to digest minima and maxima values.

Comment: @SpencerD even still, some helper funcs will help. I started working on a solution and it "parameterizes" the "bound increment", so flexibility is still possible

Comment: From the looks of "would prefer ranges like", the 1st range min is the min value itself. And the last range's max is the max value itself. The 2nd range min and max are on order of 1,000. Subsequent ranges are on order of 1,100. Doable with an "arithmetic progression" @SpencerD in stages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach that computes the minimum stepsize necessary to cover the range, then truncates it to the nearest tenth of the power of 10 which includes the stepsize and then returns the step points starting at min and finishing at max, with intermediate boundaries stepsize distance apart and the outside boundaries slightly higher to include the min/max values.

```js
const range = (min, max, steps) => {
  // minimum step size
  stepsize = (max - min) / steps;
  // increase the step size to a nice boundary
  // for example, 1/10th of the 10^n range that includes it
  pow = Math.trunc(Math.log10(stepsize)) - 1;
  stepsize = Math.trunc(stepsize / 10 ** pow) * 10 ** pow;
  // round min to the same boundary
  result = [min];
  min = Math.trunc(min / 10 ** pow) * 10 ** pow;
  for (let i = 0; i < steps - 1; i++) {
    min += stepsize;
    result.push(min);
  }
  result.push(max);
  return result;
}

console.log(range(-1234, 4321, 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

Nick's approach uses an "arithmetic progression" formula. It really is the only way to solve this.

The following solution takes into mind what @SpencerD commented on in terms of how a single arithmetic progression will not get the desired results. It's not a straight sequence, except for the "middle" parts on increment by 1,100.

As such, am posting this answer to demonstrate that all is still possible with an arithmetic progression if broken up in stages. The remaining explanation is in code comments.

```js
function lowerBound(actualValue, boundIncrement) {
    
    // lets determine the min by an arithmetic progression formula
    
    return Math.floor( actualValue / boundIncrement ) * boundIncrement
    
    
}

function upperBound(actualValue, boundIncrement) {
    
    // lets determine the max by an arithmetic progression formula, hence the + 1 for the upper range
    
    return (Math.floor( actualValue / boundIncrement ) + 1) * boundIncrement
    
}

function getRanges(min, max) {
    let nextMin = min

    // now lets use the helper funcs to determine the ranges based on "would prefer ranges like" from question

    let ranges = [];


    // if 1st range is negative, lets make it that value up to 0
    if (min < 0) {
        ranges.push([min, 0]);
        nextMin = 0;
    }


    // 2nd range requires special condition that it be on increment of 1,000

    if ( max > nextMin) {

        
        // so lets do this without conditions
        
        ranges.push([nextMin, upperBound(nextMin, 1000)]);
        nextMin = upperBound(nextMin, 1000);

    }

    // lets determine if there are subsequent ranges, on increment of 1,100
        
    if (nextMin < max) {
        
        while ( nextMin < max) {
            ranges.push([nextMin, upperBound(nextMin, 1100)])
            nextMin = upperBound(nextMin, 1100)
            
        }
        
    }


    // lastly, lets make (overwrite) the max range's max with the max value instead
    ranges[ ranges.length - 1][1] = max

    return ranges;

}

function test() {

    console.log( getRanges( parseInt(document.getElementById("min").value), parseInt(document.getElementById("max").value) ) );
}
```

```html
Enter min: <input type="text" id="min" value="-1234">
    <br>
    Enter max: <input type="text" id="max" value="4321">
    <br>
    <button onclick="test()">Console.log()</button>
```